# What do the red pips mean on Monster cards?

Tags: hand-of-fate

It seems pretty variable, but sometimes I get Monster cards with 0, 1, or 2 red pips.

[image: cards with red pips]

As far as I can tell, they don't seem to affect the encounter at all, and the dealer doesn't seem to mention the pips. So, what do they do?

Comment: I think it means they are stronger then they used to be... an upgraded form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Steam discussion, here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/266510/discussions/0/620712364045090656/), these pips are representative of enhanced power (hp, attack speed, etc) obtained from the artifacts that the dealer gives you, after every 3rd boss fight.  These artifacts also buff monsters of a certain family, so as to keep the artifact from being too powerful.

You should be able to see the descriptions of these artifacts from your adventure selection screen, on the right side, by selecting the artifacts.